# Team City 9.1.3 and IIS 8.5 Win2k12 r2 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, teamcity

I've successfully installed Team City 9.1.3 on a Win2k12 R2 server. I can get to TC by going to http://localhost:8080 - all works as it should and no issues.

However, I would like to access TC from any browser within my company. I don't want to remote desktop just to get to TC, so I followed the instructions [Here](https://blogs.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/), but I cannot get to TC through my domain. My domain is http://teamcity and is bound to a 10.* ip address since I don't want it public. I do get a reply when I ping "teamcity." Should it be a public ip?

The server is a fresh VM I created yesterday and there are no other sites on it. The server is on the domain and I can remote desktop into it.

Is there anything I need to do to associate http://teamcity or the ip address with the server?

As a test, I associated the default web site in iis with the new domain and ip address. If I navigate to either the ip address or the domain in a browser on the server, it does not take me to the default web site. Nor does that work if I do the same from my desktop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
Sys Admin fixed the issue. The ip was not bound to the server. As soon as he fixed that issue, everything is working as it should now.

Comment: Ensure that port 80 is not closed on the target IIS box. ARR should work fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: port 80 is open on the server for the domain and private. What I don't understand is that even if I open a browser and type in the ip address (which I've bound with the Default Web Site on the box for testing), the default web site is not shown. So I feel I'm missing something basic. Do I need to do anything other than bind the ip in IIS?